# How do I setup multiple memcached instances running on different ports?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, caching, debian, memcached

I am running Ubuntu 15.10 and already have memcached installed on my system. My current project requirement is to run two instances of memcached on the same server but with different ports. I start with `/etc/memcached.conf` file and check that it has option of specifying the port number. So, I thought I just need to have two identical conf files with different port numbers.

Then I check the memcached start up script `/etc/init.d/memcached` so that I could specify the location of the conf files. But to my surprise I see that the start up script already has an option to run multiple memcached instances.

```
# Usage:
# cp /etc/memcached.conf /etc/memcached_server1.conf
# cp /etc/memcached.conf /etc/memcached_server2.conf
# start all instances:
# /etc/init.d/memcached start
# start one instance:
# /etc/init.d/memcached start server1
# stop all instances:
# /etc/init.d/memcached stop
# stop one instance:
# /etc/init.d/memcached stop server1
# There is no "status" command.

FILES=(/etc/memcached_*.conf)
# check for alternative config schema
if [ -r "${FILES[0]}" ]; then
```

I tried the above option, but it still keeps starting a single instance, instead of starting two instances. Am I missing something here ?

Comment: Hello, did you find a solution for this ?

Comment: You can try the answer provided here http://askubuntu.com/a/823133/49758

Comment: Thanks ! It's perfect.

Comment: **just refer here has a solution.
qince!** -https://askubuntu.com/questions/770784/how-do-i-setup-multiple-memcached-instances-running-on-different-ports/942188#942188

Answer (score 0):

This is only guess.
init scripts may not be run because of systemd is configured as init (instead of upstart).
If so, there is a `memcached.service` script that contains memcached startup configuration.